# Handling access violations with wxWidgets

Tags: wxwidgets, access-violation

In my wxWidget program I can no longer catch Access Violation with MSVC debugger. AV info is printed in Output but program continues to run.

I suspect that wxWidgets handles this, how can I turn if off?

Comment: Answer: `wxUSE_ON_FATAL_EXCEPTION`!

Comment: Well, setting above to 0 doesn't solve problem. Question still open.

Comment: Fixed. Added "Break on exception" in MSVC.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to disable the default exception handling of wxWidgets entirely (from http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.2/overview_exceptions.html):

> To use any kind of exception support in the library you need to build it with wxUSE_EXCEPTIONS set to 1. It is turned on by default but you may wish to check include/wx/msw/setup.h file under Windows or run configure with explicit --enable-exceptions argument under Unix.
>   On the other hand, if you do not plan to use exceptions, setting this flag to 0 or using --disable-exceptions could result in a leaner and slightly faster library.